# How to run batch file after file download (from Linux to Windows) throught FTP in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I am doing file copy from Linux to Windows share through FTP.

Once copy is done I am moving it to isilon storage which is shared on network  path (manually).

Now I have created a batch file, which will do copy from FTP shared path to network path.

So how can I start batch file after FTP download? How can I automate it completely?

from Linux

```
ftp -n ip
user "user" "pwd"
put app.tar.gz
```

Once it is done i want to move it network shared path

Comment: you should be able to execute like this cp /ftp/directory; another_command_with_your_script but without any clarification on wich command you are executing I cannot help you... May be you are ussing the wrong aproach. I think that is perfectly possible to copy directly from the ftp to the nas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `copy` command in a batch file, after the `ftp.exe` finishes:

```
ftp.exe -s:download.txt
copy c:\dowloadtarget\myfile.txt \\server\share\target\myfile.txt
```

---

You can run the copy even from the FTP script (the `download.txt`), if you need it for some reason. Use the `!` (escape to shell) command.

```
get /remote/path/myfile.txt c:\dowloadtarget\myfile.txt
! copy c:\dowloadtarget\myfile.txt \\server\share\target\myfile.txt
```

---

But why don't you download the file directly to the shared folder?

```
get /remote/path/myfile.txt \\server\share\target\myfile.txt
```